# ListView's scroll is not smooth in Flutter project

Tags: android, ios, listview, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I just started learning Flutter. And I faced one big problem which is bad scrolling in complex list. Let's say we have 5 different item type in our ListView and some item type must display images and it's infinite scroll. I read a lot articles and posts about ListView for Flutter and all the things I've seen are simple list with text. How can I make smooth scroll?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Startup Name Generator',
      home: new RandomWords(),
    );
  }
}

class RandomWords extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  RandomWordsState createState() => new RandomWordsState();
}

class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final List<WordPair> _suggestions = <WordPair>[];
  final TextStyle _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
  List<int> items = List.generate(10, (i) => i);
  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  bool isPerformingRequest = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        _getMoreData();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _getMoreData() async {
    if (!isPerformingRequest) {
      setState(() => isPerformingRequest = true);
      List<int> newEntries = await fakeRequest(
          items.length, items.length + 10); //returns empty list
      if (newEntries.isEmpty) {
        double edge = 50.0;
        double offsetFromBottom = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent -
            _scrollController.position.pixels;
        if (offsetFromBottom < edge) {
          _scrollController.animateTo(
              _scrollController.offset - (edge - offsetFromBottom),
              duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: Curves.easeOut);
        }
      }
      setState(() {
        items.addAll(newEntries);
        isPerformingRequest = false;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<List<int>> fakeRequest(int from, int to) async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      return List.generate(to - from, (i) => i + from);
    });
  }

  Widget _buildProgressIndicator() {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new Opacity(
          opacity: isPerformingRequest ? 1.0 : 0.0,
          child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(""),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length + 1,

        itemBuilder: (context, index) {

          if (index == items.length) {
            return _buildProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            if (index % 5 == 0) {
              return Image.network(
                "http://sanctum-inle-resort.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Sanctum_Inl_Resort_Myanmar_Flowers_Frangipani.jpg",
                height: 200.0,
              );
            } else if (index.isOdd) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                  title: Text('This is title'),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return ListTile(title: new Text("Number $index"));
            }
          }
        },
        controller: _scrollController,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it only slow in development mode or also when you made an release build?

Comment: @JoranDob I haven't test in release build but it shouldn't happen in debug build.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the fact that you request the data async when the user is already to the end of the list and has no more items and then it's performing a fake request which loads the data but this takes a sec so that's why it's studdering

```
_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent
```

This gets the end of the scroll list so it starts loading at the point the user is at the end of the list you could change this value with an offset so it starts loading earlier

To test this you could try changing:

```
   if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
      _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
```

To:

```
   if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
      (_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent - 50)) {
```

And

```
  Future<List<int>> fakeRequest(int from, int to) async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      return List.generate(to - from, (i) => i + from);
    });
  }
```

To:

```
List<int> fakeRequest(int from, int to) {
         return List.generate(to - from, (i) => i + from);
      }
```

Comment: Actually smooth scroll problem is not based on it. Let's say we have 100 items already including image items. In that case, scroll will not be smooth anymore.